# Error in Shopping Cart Magento 2.2.4

Tags: shopping-cart, magento2.2.4

Preconditions

Magento 2.2.4 (upgraded from Magento 2.2.3 successfully)

Steps to reproduce

Go to configurable product in Frontend and add it to Shopping Cart (e.g. 1 x T-Shirt in Size L and colour white )
In the same product, add another one (e.g. 1 x T-Shirt in Size M and colour red) to Shopping Cart

Expected result

There are two products (1 x T-Shirt in size L and colour white and 1 x T-Shirt in size M and colour red)
in Mini-Shopping Cart and normal Shopping Cart

Actual result

By adding 1 x T-Shirt (L, white) everything is ok.
But if I add a second T-Shirt (M, red) within the same product, in the shopping carts is shown 1 x T-Shirt in L, white and 2 x T-Shirts in M, red, although I only added one product each.
The strange thing is, that if I refresh the site between adding the two T-Shirts, everything is shown correctly.
That means:
Adding first T-Shirt (L, white) to cart -> ok -> refresh the product site in frontend-> adding second T-Shirt (M, red) to cart -> everything is ok.

Can somebody reproduce this error?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by following the instructions here

[https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/pull/227/commits/e37a048ffa0b397030adb9718f7bd641bc494492#diff-344694152fc7ddf8eb51f4080fc26faf][1]